# How to display each instance of a user logging into a server with a button click?

Tags: java, button, authentication, xml-rpc, summary

I have been tasked with creating a recycling machine server which a engineer can log into empty, reset, etc. Each time the engineer logs into a machine it creates a string that says "Engineer has logged in on this (date)". I need to create a JButton that prints out each instance of this string being written.

So when pressed it prints out something like this:

> "Engineer visited this machine on 01/01/2016"
>
> "Engineer visited this machine on 02/01/2016"
>
> "Engineer visited this machine on 05/04/2016"

The log in function is working and uses stored cookies to figure out if the user has input the correct information. I am however unable to figure out how to print out this summary of visits via one button click. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
package com.perisic.beds.peripherals;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;

import org.apache.xmlrpc.WebServer;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient;

import com.perisic.beds.machine.CustomerPanel;


/**
 * A Simple Graphical User Interface for the Recycling Machine.
 * @author Group M
 *
 */
public class RecyclingGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5772727482959492839L;
    //CustomerPanel myCustomerPanel = new CustomerPanel(new Display());
    Display myDisplay = new Display();
    
    ReceiptPrinter printer = new ReceiptPrinter();
    ReceiptPrinter printer2 = new ReceiptPrinter();
    
    CustomerPanel myCustomerPanel = new CustomerPanel(myDisplay);
    CustomerPanel machineScreen = new CustomerPanel(printer2);
    CustomerPanel theConsole = new CustomerPanel(printer);
    CustomerPanel thePanel = new CustomerPanel(myDisplay);
    
    private String storedPasswd = "123"; // needs some thinking with encryption etc
    private String storedCookie = null; // some random string to be used for authentication
    private String sessionCookie = "";
    
    private int numberOfVisits = 0;
    

    
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    Date storedDate = new Date();
    /**
     * Web service to provide number of items in the machine. 
     * @param myCookie
     * @return
     */
    
    public int numberOfItems(String myCookie) {
        if( storedCookie == null ) { 
            return -1; 
        } else if( myCookie.equals(storedCookie)) { 
            return myCustomerPanel.getNumberOfItems(); 
        } 
        else { 
            return -1; 
        }
    }
    
    public int empty (String myCookie){
        if(storedCookie == null){
            return -1;
        }else if(myCookie.equals(storedCookie)){
            return myCustomerPanel.empty();
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
     
    /**
     * Web service to authenticate the user with proper password. 
     * @param passwd
     * @return
     */
    
    public String login(String passwd) { 
        if( passwd.equals(storedPasswd)) { 
         storedCookie = "MC"+Math.random(); 
         System.out.println("Engineer has logged in on: " + dateFormat.format(date));
         storedDate = date;
         numberOfVisits ++;
         return storedCookie;
     } else { 
         return "Incorrect Password";
     }
    } 
    
    public String visits(String myCookie){
        if(numberOfVisits == 0){
            return "Engineer has not visited this machine";
        }else if(myCookie.equals(storedCookie)){
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVisits; i++){
            System.out.println("Engineer has visited on these dates: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate));
            }
            return storedCookie;
        }else{
            return "Engineer has visited on these date: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate);
        }
    }
    
     /**
      * Web service to logout from the system. 
      */
     
    public String logout(String myCookie ) { 
        if( storedCookie == null ) { 
            return "(no cookie set)"; 
        } else if( myCookie.equals(storedCookie)) { 
            System.out.println("Engineer has logged out on: " + dateFormat.format(date));
            storedCookie = null;  
            return "cookie deleted: OK"; 
        } 
        else { 
            return "could not delete anything; authentication missing"; 
        }
    }

    
    public static final String SUN_JAVA_COMMAND = "sun.java.command";
    
    //This method is used to restart the application.
    //It uses code that basically stores all of the necessary code it will need to successfully restart the application.
    //Rather then just using System.exit(0) which, by itself would simply close the entire application.
    //Using dispose() and new RecyclingGUI also doesn't work as it does not reload the JPanel upon restarting.
    public void restartApplication(Runnable runBeforeRestart) throws IOException{
        try {
            String java = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java";
            List<String> vmArguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
            StringBuffer vmArgsOneLine = new StringBuffer();
            for (String arg : vmArguments) {
                if (!arg.contains("-agentlib")) {
                    vmArgsOneLine.append(arg);
                    vmArgsOneLine.append(" ");
                }
            }
            final StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer("\"" + java + "\" " + vmArgsOneLine);
            String[] mainCommand = System.getProperty(SUN_JAVA_COMMAND).split(" ");
            if (mainCommand[0].endsWith(".jar")) {
            cmd.append("-jar " + new File(mainCommand[0]).getPath());
            } else {
                cmd.append("-cp \"" + System.getProperty("java.class.path") + "\" " + mainCommand[0]);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < mainCommand.length; i++) {
                cmd.append(" ");
                cmd.append(mainCommand[i]);
            }
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            if (runBeforeRestart!= null) {
                runBeforeRestart.run();
            }
        System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Error while trying to restart the machine", e);
        }
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /* Differentiate between the different buttons pressed and initiate appropriate
         * actions
         */
        try{
            XmlRpcClient server = new XmlRpcClient("http://localhost:100");
    //This code allows the engineer to login to the machine and when they do it reveals new buttons that only the engineer can use.
            if (e.getSource().equals(login)){
                String message;
        
                boolean loginSuccess = false;
                while(loginSuccess == false && (message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Login please"))!= null){
                    Vector parms1 = new Vector();
                    parms1.add(message);
                    Object result3 = server.execute("recycling.login", parms1);
                    String loginRequest = result3.toString();
                    if(loginRequest.equals("Wrong password")){
                        System.out.println("Wrong Password. Try Again!");
                    } else {
                        sessionCookie = loginRequest;
                        System.out.println("You are now logged in");
                        login.setVisible(false);
                        logout.setVisible(true);
                        reset.setVisible(true);
                        empty.setVisible(true);
                        items.setVisible(true);
                        loginSuccess = true;
                    }
                }
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(visits)){
                Vector params = new Vector();
                params.add(sessionCookie);
                Object result = server.execute("recycling.visits", params);
                System.out.println(result);
            
                
            //This logs the engineer out of the machine and hides some of the buttons
            }else if( e.getSource().equals(logout)) { 
                Vector params = new Vector(); 
                params.add(sessionCookie); 
                Object result = server.execute("recycling.logout", params ); 
                System.out.println("Logout: "+result);
                reset.setVisible(false);
                empty.setVisible(false);
                items.setVisible(false);
                login.setVisible(true);
                logout.setVisible(false);
                
                //This code tells the engineer how many items are currently in the machine.
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(items)){
                Vector params = new Vector(); 
                params.add(sessionCookie); 
                Object result = server.execute("recycling.numberOfItems", params ); 
                int resultInt = new Integer(result.toString()); 
                if( resultInt == -1 ) { 
                    System.out.println("Sorry no authentication there."); 
                } else { 
                    System.out.println("There are "+resultInt+" items in the machine");
                }
                
                //This if statement empties all items that have been put into the machine thus far and sets the item number property to 0
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(empty)){
                Vector params = new Vector();
                params.add(sessionCookie);
                Object result = server.execute("recycling.empty", params);
                int resultInt = new Integer(result.toString());
                if(resultInt == -1){
                    System.out.println("Sorry no authentication there.");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("The machine has been emptied.");
                }
                
                //This method coded above is called here.
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(reset)){
                restartApplication(null);
                
                
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(slot1)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.itemReceived(1);
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(slot2)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.itemReceived(2);
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(slot3)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.itemReceived(3);
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(slot4)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.itemReceived(4);
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(receipt)) { 
                myCustomerPanel.printReceipt();
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(display)) {
                this.myCustomerPanel = thePanel;
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(console)){
                myCustomerPanel = theConsole;
            }else if(e.getSource().equals(onScreen)){
                //once this button is clicked all output is linked back into the GUI
                myCustomerPanel = machineScreen;
                redirectSystemStreams();    
            }
            
            
        }catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("JavaClient: " + exception);
        }
        // System.out.println("Received: e.getActionCommand()="+e.getActionCommand()+
        //                  " e.getSource()="+e.getSource().toString() ); 
        
        
    }
    
    //This Adds the controls (buttons) to the GUI
        JButton slot1 = new JButton("Can"); 
        JButton slot2 = new JButton("Bottle"); 
        JButton slot3 = new JButton("Crate");
        JButton slot4 = new JButton("Paper Bag");
        JButton receipt = new JButton("Print Receipt"); 
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        JButton empty = new JButton("Empty");
        JButton items = new JButton("#Items");
        JButton visits = new JButton("visits");
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20,30);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        JButton display = new JButton("Print to Display");
        JButton console = new JButton("Print to GUI/Console");
        JButton onScreen = new JButton("Show On Screen");
        
        /** This creates the GUI using the controls above and
         *  adds the actions and listeners. this area of code also 
         *  Contains the panel settings for size and some behaviours.
        */
        public RecyclingGUI() {
            super();
            setSize(500, 600);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
            panel.add(slot1); 
            panel.add(slot2);
            panel.add(slot3);
            panel.add(slot4);
            
            slot1.addActionListener(this); 
            slot2.addActionListener(this); 
            slot3.addActionListener(this);
            slot4.addActionListener(this);
            
            panel.add(receipt); 
            receipt.addActionListener(this); 
            panel.add(display);
            display.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(console);
            console.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(onScreen);
            onScreen.addActionListener(this);
            
            /**Text Area controls for size, font style, font size
             * the text area also has a scroll bar just in case the user enters 
             * a large number of items
             */
            panel.add(scroll);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            textArea.setFont(new Font("Ariel",Font.PLAIN, 14));
            scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            
            panel.add(login);
            login.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(logout);
            logout.setVisible(false);
            logout.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(reset);
            reset.setVisible(false);
            reset.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(items);
            items.setVisible(false);
            items.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(empty);
            empty.setVisible(false);
            empty.addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(visits);
            visits.addActionListener(this);
            
            getContentPane().add(panel);
            panel.repaint();
        
        }
    
    public static void main(String [] args ) { 
        RecyclingGUI myGUI = new RecyclingGUI(); 
        myGUI.setVisible(true); 
        try {
               System.out.println("Starting the Recycling Server..."); 
               WebServer server = new WebServer(100);
               server.addHandler("recycling", myGUI);
               server.start();
              } catch (Exception exception) {
               System.err.println("JavaServer: " + exception);
               }
              
    }
    /** This is the code that redirects where the code is displayed
     *  from the console to the textArea of the GUI. it does this by 
     *  creating a new set of output streams (for text and errors) which 
     *  are set as default when the redirectSystemStream method is called.
     *  (from a previous piece of work i did in my FDg, source = from a tutorial)
     */
    public void updateTextArea(final String text) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              textArea.append(text);
            }
          });
        }
         
        public void redirectSystemStreams() {
          OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
              updateTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
            }
         
            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
              updateTextArea(new String(b, off, len));
            }
         
            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
              write(b, 0, b.length);
            }
          };
         
          System.setOut(new PrintStream(out, true));
          System.setErr(new PrintStream(out, true));
        }
    
    public void print(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after working around with the code for a while I discovered that there was one simple piece of code that was causing it to not display the information I wanted.

```
private int numberOfVisits = 0;
```

Defining the int as a 0 to begin with caused the code to reset the value of the int every time I pressed the "visits" button.

Removing the 0 fixed this issue.

```
private int numberOfVisits;
```